# Minimized JSON code between two patterns with regex

Tags: sed, regular-expression, json

Let's take a file with for example :

```
                        "test": [
                           {
                           }
                        ],
                        "test": [
                           {
                              "name":"bob",
                              "age":21
                           }
                        ]
```

Is there a way for a regex to minimize the code into something like this :

```
                        "test": [{}],
                        "test": [{"name":"bob","age":21}]
```

Comment: Why not use `jq` or some other appropriate tool? Regular expressions (chomsky type-3) and context-free languages (type-2) like JSON don't mix well.

Comment: The two documents are equivalent when parsed with a JSON parser. Use a JSON parser.

Comment: I would not downvote this question. Been handling a bit of JSON with python, redis and bash lately and it is extremely hard to find simple and clear documentation to handle `jq`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two keys `test` actually are unique (the second `test` would otherwise override the first `test` when parsing it with a JSON parser), and that the document is a well formed JSON document, use `jq -c` to produce a compact version of it.

Here, I've changed the names of the keys so that they are unique, and encapsulated the JSON fragment in an anonymous object:

```
$ cat file.json
{
  "test1": [
    {}
  ],
  "test2": [
    {
      "name": "bob",
      "age": 21
    }
  ]
}

$ jq -c . file.json
{"test1":[{}],"test2":[{"name":"bob","age":21}]}
```

The `.` on the command line is a `jq` filter that passes the document through without modifying the contents.

Comment: Good answer, +1. The `jq` documentation is very convoluted, simple examples are more  than needed.